# Call a subroutine/function in Global.asa from an ASP page?

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

In Classic ASP, shouldn't a subroutine in global.asa be available to all .asp pages in the application? For some reason I am having trouble calling the sub. Before I look at whether something specific to my application is causing the problem I wanted to make sure I understood properly.

global.asa:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript" RUNAT="Server">
  sub foo
    session("foo") = true
  end sub
</SCRIPT>
```

myinclude.inc, included in all pages:

```
call foo
```

I get 'Type Mismatch' runtime error referencing foo. Am I totally misunderstanding this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't declare global functions like that.  To quote the [documenation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525316%28VS.90%29.aspx):

> Procedures declared in the Global.asa file can be called only from one or more of the scripts associated with the Application_OnStart, Application_OnEnd, Session_OnStart, and Session_OnEnd events. They are not available to the ASP pages in the ASP-based application.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I was able to include some code on every page to do what I wanted to do, so no matter which page was the first one requested my code runs.